# Plot Neural Network model for MLP model created using caret package

Tags: r, neural-network, r-caret, mlp

I have successfully created a multilayer perceptron model using caret package in r. How do I plot the neural network model? My code is as below

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats =5)
mlpMLFit <- train(demand ~ ., data = datatrain, method = "mlpML", trControl = ctrl, preProcess = c("center", "scale"), tuneLength = 20)
mlpMLFit
plot(mlpMLFit)
summary(mlpMLFit)
```

the code `plot(mlpMLFit)` only plot the RMSE against Hidden Units as shown below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't quite work because `mlpMLFit` in your example is a `train` object for caret. I think a good and safe way might be to fit the model again with your best tune parameters, for example:

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
data(BostonHousing)
ctrl <- trainControl(method="cv", number=4)
TG = expand.grid(layer1=2:4,layer2=2:4,layer3=2:4)
mlpMLFit <- train(medv ~ ., data = BostonHousing, method = "mlpML", trControl = ctrl, preProcess = c("center", "scale"), tuneGrid=TG)
```

We use `mlp()` to refit the model:

```
library(RSNNS)
library(devtools)
source_url('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fawda123/7471137/raw/466c1474d0a505ff044412703516c34f1a4684a5/nnet_plot_update.r')

fit = mlp(x=model.matrix(medv ~ .,data=BostonHousing),
y=BostonHousing$medv,size=as.numeric(mlpMLFit$bestTune))
```

And you can use the plot function described [here](https://beckmw.wordpress.com/2013/11/14/visualizing-neural-networks-in-r-update/):

```
library(devtools)
source_url('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/fawda123/7471137/raw/466c1474d0a505ff044412703516c34f1a4684a5/nnet_plot_update.r')

plot.nnet(fit)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, I am trying to use this but I have a non-numeric y column. I get " ''y' has to be numeric, after a conversion to matrix'when running "fit = mlp(". Is there a way I can use this with a non-numeric y ? Thank you